# Scrollbar location within a UL

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I've looked at other questions but I can't seem to find an answer...

```
if($("#my-list").pageYOffset > 541){
$("#my-list").scrollTo("-=540px");
}
```

This is my code. As you can see, I'm trying to use jQuery or just some JavaScript to identify where I've scrolled to in my unordered list (which has a vertical scroll due to overflow:scroll). If this target offset meets a certain threshold, I want it to bump back up to the beginning.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pageYOffset gives how far the entire page has been scrolled, but as far as I understand you want to observe the scrolltop offset of `#my-list`'s children (i.e. `li`) relative to their parent (i.e. the `ul`). So the function would have to look something like

```
$("#my-list").scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>541) {
         $(this).scrollTop("0px");   
    }
});
```

For a working example look at http://jsfiddle.net/LFE2v/

Comment: Tomm -- Thanks, this seems helpful. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it working. Two things: the scrollTop function seems to return the right values if I use #my-list as a parameter instead of this, but whenever I reach 541 px, the list does not pop back up. Here is what I now have:

 $("#my-list").scroll(function() {
     if($("#my-list").scrollTop()>541) {
          $("#my-list").scrollTo("0px");   
     }
 });

Comment: I suppose you're using the ScrollTo plugin ([link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo))? Have you checked that this is working allright for you? As a fall back you could always use jQuery's native .scrollTop() function which does what you want, without animation of course.

Comment: By the way, it just occured to me that using the ScrollTo plugin might be overcooking it a bit. Why not use something like this `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#scroll").scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop()>100) {
          $(this).stop().animate({"scrollTop":"0px"}, 800);
        }  
    });
});` or look http://jsfiddle.net/LFE2v/7/

Comment: I figured it out -- thanks for the extra help, but in the end, I just needed a little extra debugging with my numbers >_<

Also, for some reason, scrollTop() did not do anything for me, but scrollTo("0px") did. In case anyone is interested, here is my stuff:  $("#my-list").scroll(
  function() { 
   if($("#my-list").scrollTop()>370) { 
    $("#my-list").scrollTo("0px"); 
   } 
  }
 );